# anacron not running weekly scripts

Tags: debian, cron, anacron

/etc/anacrontab:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

/etc/cron.d/anacron:

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7-23 * * *   root    [ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi
```

This suggests cron does not execute anacron, but is left for systemd to handle, correct? Can't see any relevant systemd timers for it though:

```
$ systemctl list-timers --all
NEXT                          LEFT LAST                               PASSED UNIT                         ACTIVATES                     
Sun 2023-10-29 11:36:44 CET  17min Sun 2023-10-29 10:03:38 CET  1h 15min ago fwupd-refresh.timer          fwupd-refresh.service
Sun 2023-10-29 17:27:57 CET     6h Sat 2023-10-28 18:27:57 CEST      17h ago etckeeper.timer              etckeeper.service
Sun 2023-10-29 17:27:57 CET     6h Sat 2023-10-28 18:27:57 CEST      17h ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Sun 2023-10-29 18:07:00 CET     6h Sun 2023-10-29 09:22:36 CET  1h 56min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Mon 2023-10-30 00:00:00 CET    12h Sun 2023-10-29 00:00:01 CEST      12h ago apt-show-versions.timer      apt-show-versions.service
Mon 2023-10-30 00:00:00 CET    12h Sun 2023-10-29 00:00:01 CEST      12h ago dpkg-db-backup.timer         dpkg-db-backup.service
Mon 2023-10-30 00:00:00 CET    12h Sun 2023-10-29 00:00:01 CEST      12h ago logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Mon 2023-10-30 01:29:34 CET    14h Mon 2023-10-23 08:14:40 CEST            - fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
Mon 2023-10-30 06:22:39 CET    19h Sun 2023-10-29 10:19:49 CET     59min ago man-db.timer                 man-db.service
Mon 2023-10-30 06:25:00 CET    19h Sun 2023-10-29 06:25:01 CET  4h 54min ago ntpsec-rotate-stats.timer    ntpsec-rotate-stats.service
Mon 2023-10-30 06:46:54 CET    19h Sun 2023-10-29 06:25:35 CET  4h 53min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Sun 2023-11-05 03:10:25 CET 6 days Sun 2023-10-29 03:10:49 CET        8h ago e2scrub_all.timer            e2scrub_all.service
```

Running `sudo anacron -n` to trigger execution.

/var/log/cron.log after the run:

```
2023-10-25T16:46:45.570141+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-10-25
2023-10-25T16:46:45.578029+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Will run job `cron.daily'
2023-10-25T16:46:45.578146+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Will run job `cron.monthly'
2023-10-25T16:46:45.578220+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
2023-10-25T16:46:45.578716+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Job `cron.daily' started
2023-10-25T16:46:45.583688+03:00 hostname anacron[704605]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2023-10-25
2023-10-25T16:47:23.041584+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Job `cron.daily' terminated (mailing output)
2023-10-25T16:47:23.042011+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Job `cron.monthly' started
2023-10-25T16:47:23.047447+03:00 hostname anacron[705937]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.monthly' to 2023-10-25
2023-10-25T16:47:23.047590+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Job `cron.monthly' terminated
2023-10-25T16:47:23.055468+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Tried to mail output of job `cron.daily', but mailer process (/usr/sbin/sendmail) exited with status 78
2023-10-25T16:47:23.055626+03:00 hostname anacron[704597]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
```

What gives, why weeklies aren't ran?

---

Edit: dailies are not executed either. created `hosts-block-update-daily` in `/etc/cron.daily` with

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "start @ $(date)" >> /home/mylocaluser/hosts-update-daily.log
```

and nothing is logged. They're only executed if anacron is ran manually as discussed in comments below.

Comment: Was the weekly job possibly run less than 7 days ago?  If you want to run _all_ jobs (ignoring timestamps), use `anacron -f`.

Comment: @Kusalananda looks like you're right, `-f` flag schedules it. Any hint as to how to see why at least one of the scripts there is failing to run? `sudo run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly` certainly succeeds - script in `/etc/cron.weekly` executes as expected.

Comment: Anacron does not run jobs that were run more recently than what's specified in the `anacrontab` file.  If you try `anacron -n` again (as in the question), does it run any jobs at all?

Comment: I can confirm the weekly script in question executes fine via `anacron -n`, confirmed by a timestamp of a file it modifies. Yet left to its own devices it never fires. Computer is rarely shut down/suspended.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue, you may want to leave a simple writeup of the solution as an answer below. You should be able to "accept" the answer after some time, which would mark the issue as "resolved". See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The core of the problem still exists as mentioned - `Yet left to its own devices it never fires`

Comment: Is there a service or cron job that actually runs `anacron` every once in a while? As far as I know, `anacron` is not a daemon in itself.

Comment: Added `/etc/cron.d/anacron` contents to the Q. Looks like regular cron skips it if `/run/systemd/system` dir exists. So possibly systemd is supposed to launch anacron but fails to do so? Note `systemctl | grep anac` yields nothing.